# How to extract the just the date from a file path string that also includes time with the format 2020.04.12.10.30.10?

Tags: r, regex

I have a filepath string that looks like this:

```
\\\\server\file\path\string\10X_blah.2020.04.12.10.30.10.xls
```

I need to extract just 2020.04.12

I've tried `(?<=\.).*(?=\.)`

but it matches the whole date and time, I am having trouble learning how to limit it to just the first part of the match, the part that corresponds to date.

I'm using R and `mutate(date = str_extract(filepath, pattern)` to make a new column in my dataframe. I just don't know the regex to find just the date.

Comment: Perhaps matching `\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}` would be enough  without the lookbehind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is that:

```
\\d{4}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}
```

In R:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(my_string,"\\d{4}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}")
[[1]]
[1] "2020.04.12"
```

explanation:

1. `\\d{4}\\.`four digit year followed by a dot
2. `\\d{2}\\.`two digit month followed by a dot
3. `\\d{2}` two digit day

Comment: Edited because R uses double slashes for escaping instead of one backslash.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very strong solution because it requires locating the length before `substring`ing. A lookahead might be more ideal. Nevertheless, we can do:

```
my_string<- readClipboard() # copy the file path

substring(stringr::str_remove_all(my_string,"\\D.*(?=\\d{4,})"),
          1,10)
[1] "2020.04.12"
```

If you know the exact pattern(ie that 10 always follows a . and that 10 always exists), then maybe:

```
stringr::str_remove_all(my_string,"\\D.*(?=\\d{4,})|\\.10.*")
[1] "2020.04.12"
```